# Android Firebase database threading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I understood, Firebase Database performs all the reading tasks on a single thread.

Is there a way to split that work into few different threads?

Is there a way to make a tasks execute before another? some parallel to handler.postAtFrontOfQueue() ?

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase client handles all network and disk I/O on a separate thread to avoid interfering with the UI of your Android app. The callbacks into your code are invoked on the main thread, so that your code can interact with the UI.

The operations are executed in the same order in which you call their APIs. There is no way to re-order operations. There is also no way to set up multiple threads, nor have I ever seen a need for that. Interacting with a remote service is inherently an I/O intensive operations, which is not helped by multi-threading.

This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve, we may be able to help better.